# Any other Linux application similar to Greyhole?

Tags: linux

Is there any other Linux application similar to [Greyhole](http://www.greyhole.net/)? Preferably without relying on Samba? My usage is for a typical home server.

edit: I don't know if it wasn't clear, but the features that I want are what Greyhole has (from the link):

- JBOD concatenation storage pool
- Per-share redundancy
- Easily recoverable files

Comment: Atleast conceptually, it looks like Greyhole is just a simplified interface to mdadm and samba. What experience do you have with Linux? Setting up either of these is not particularly difficult, with a bit of research.

Comment: @MatthewScharley I have already tried LVM and it doesn't have the features I'm looking for. I found Greyhole and I'm considering using it. However, I was thinking if there is an alternative that doesn't use samba but google isn't very helpful in finding it.

Comment: Rather than listing things that don't have the features you want, why don't you tell us the features you *do* want?  Much less guessing involved that way.

Comment: "My usage is for a typical home server" questions about home servers are off topic, see the FAQ

Answer (score 1):

There are several Linux technologies that can provide a similar effect.  The following are the big two:

1. **Logical Volume Management (LVM)** - Add as many block devices (HDD, thumb drive, SD card, etc.) as you want to increase storage space.  The block devices can be any size, type etc.    No redundancy (well, there's mirroring, but that's not useful in this use-case).
2. **Redundant Array of Independent Disks (RAID)** - Add several disks of the same size to an array.  Provides scalable storage and/or redundancy depending on the RAID type used.

Then you can then export the storage to users using NFS, Samba/CIFS, Web, FTP, etc.

Comment: LVM and RAID don't have easily recoverable files or do they? One feature of Greyhole is being able to take out a hard drive from the pool, mount it anywhere else, and see the files Greyhole stored in it.